# Symfony and Doctrine, how do I join with a subquery as clause?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'll admit I'm kinda new at both Symfony and Doctrine but I can't find a way to join a table that has multiple details for each row on the starting table, so I only want the max(date) row out of that
The raw SQL would be something like

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN activities on activities.user_id = users.id 
    and activity.date = (select max(date) 
        from activities a2 
        where a2.user_id = activites.user_id 
        and activities.date <= sysdate)
```

I've tried putting the RAW clause in the ->leftJoin method but it's not working

```
$query->leftJoin('p.activities', 'att', 'WITH', 'att.date = (select max(a2.date) from activities a2 where att.user_id = a2.user_id and a2.date< sysdate)');
```

this results in a

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 133 near 'activities a2 where': Error: Class 'activities' is not defined.
```

If I remove that where clause the join works fine though (but obviously returns too many rows)

Is there a way to do this with Doctrine? I can't convert the whole thing to raw SQL cause there are way more joins and conditions to apply after this (filtering results on a list page)

PS: I'm on Symfony 3.4, if that changes anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was as easy as defining the actual class instead of the table name, so \AppBundle\Entity\Activities

Changing that (and the name fields to the entity properties) fixed the error and works fine